# Comparing 1 row to multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, database, data-analysis

I am trying to match the value between two strings, but I have a problem comparing rows in different tables.

I want to check if 1 row has exactly >= 95% of similarity in multiple rows. If it does then the loop stops, if the similarity does not match then it will check the other rows in the table matching until the loop finds the match.

[image]

Comment: Similarity is not a sql function, so you would need to create something by yourself in order to meassure that similarity that you are looking for. I recommend you to read about fuzzy matching algorithms.

Comment: Which DB engine are you using? Depending on your DB back-end there may be text search functions available to do the match scoring for you